# Split Texture using a Curved Line in Unity3D C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textures, curve, texture2d

I have a texture that I want to slice into 2 parts, using a Vector2 array. 
I have all the Vector2 points for the curved line.

**Question**

How can I slice the texture into 2 parts using the curved line of points.

**Alternative Solutions/Questions**

How can I 'pixel' fill a Vector2[] shape to create a Texture?

---

**My attempts**

1) Generating Vector2 points to create a square, with the top part being the curve edge. Looked promising but when I tried generating a Mesh, the points sorting was incorrect.

2) Dynamically created a Polygon2D Collider - mimicking the bottom part of the sliced texture - this had the same issue as attempt 1, the point ordering. So when convert the Collider to Mesh, it obviously had the same results as attempt

---

In the picture below:

1. The red line simulates my Vector2 array
2. The gray+green square is the texture 1024 x 1024 pixels
3. The green area is the target area I want

[image: Texture Slice Example]

Comment: What did you look for so far in the Unity docs, and SO in general, but didn't find you any results? (mostly because your question seems to miss the part that explains what you've search/researched and tried so far)

Comment: So...you need *two* new textures that you can *write to* with either the original texture's pixel data or transparency....

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans will edit my question to include what I have attempted, thanks

Comment: @Draco18s It only requires 1 texture, then, using the Vector2 array to remove the pixels above the 'line'.

Comment: I would go with working with Mesh. I'd generate a Mesh by filling its vertices array from your 2D curve, plus 2 vertices on the top (or bottom) edge of the square. Then UV-map the texture on this new mesh so as if I was mapping on the full square mesh. Then render it into a RenderTexture. I mean this is not the most optimal solution, you might have issues with resolution, it might not be pixel perfect etc. but its robust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes a mesh that is the shape you want (but with jagged edges on top), hopefully that is a step in the right direction.  The Vector2 points[] array contains your red line.  It should be sorted by the x coordinate, and all the numbers should be between 0 and 1.  Needs a mesh filter and a mesh renderer with your texture.

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshFilter))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshRenderer))]
public class createMesh : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start () {
        Vector2[] points = new Vector2[4];
        points [0] = new Vector2 (0, .5f);
        points [1] = new Vector2 (.33f, 1f);
        points [2] = new Vector2 (.66f, .5f);
        points [3] = new Vector2 (1, 1f);

        MeshFilter mf = GetComponent<MeshFilter> ();
        Mesh mesh = new Mesh();


        Vector3[] verticies = new Vector3[points.Length * 2];
        int[] triangles = new int[(points.Length - 1)*6];
        Vector3[] normals = new Vector3[points.Length * 2];
        Vector2[] uv = new Vector2[points.Length * 2];

        int vIndex = 0;
        int tIndex = 0;
        int nIndex = 0;
        int uvIndex = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i< points.Length; i++) {
            Vector3 topVert = points[i];
            Vector3 bottomVert = topVert;
            bottomVert.y = 0;
            verticies[vIndex++]= bottomVert;
            verticies[vIndex++]=topVert;

            //uv
            uv[uvIndex++] = bottomVert;
            uv[uvIndex++] = topVert;

            //normals
            normals[nIndex++] = -Vector3.forward;
            normals[nIndex++] = -Vector3.forward;

            if (i<points.Length - 1) {
                //triangles
                triangles[tIndex++] = (i)*2;
                triangles[tIndex++] = (i)*2+1;
                triangles[tIndex++] = (i)*2+2;
                triangles[tIndex++] = (i)*2+2;
                triangles[tIndex++] = (i)*2+1;
                triangles[tIndex++] = (i)*2+3;

            }
        }

        mesh.vertices = verticies;
        mesh.triangles = triangles;
        mesh.normals = normals;
        mesh.uv = uv;

        mf.mesh = mesh;
    }
}
```

Bonus: here's a way to do it just with the texture.  To use this the bitmap has to be set to Advanced, with read/write enabled in the import settings.  This method uses 0 to 1023 (or however large your texture is) for coordinates, and should work for numbers out of that range too.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;


public class tex2d : MonoBehaviour {

    public Vector2[] points;

    void Start () {
        MeshRenderer mr;
        Texture2D t2d;
        Texture2D newTex = new Texture2D (1024, 1024);

        mr = GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ();
        t2d = mr.material.GetTexture (0) as Texture2D;
        MakeTex (points, t2d, ref newTex, 1024);
        mr.material.SetTexture (0, newTex);
    }


    void MakeTex(Vector2[] pnts, Texture2D inputTex, ref Texture2D outputTex, int size){

        Color bgcolor = new Color (1, 0, 1, 1);
        for (int i=0; i<(pnts.Length-1); i++) {
            Vector2 p1=pnts[i];
            Vector2 p2=pnts[i+1];

            //skip points that are out of range
            if ((p1.x <0 && p2.x <0) || (p1.x > size && p2.x>size)) continue;

            for (int x =(int)p1.x; x<(int)p2.x; x++) {
                if (x<0) continue;
                if (x>=size) break;

                float interpX = (x-p1.x)/(p2.x-p1.x);
                int interpY = (int) ((p2.y-p1.y)*interpX + p1.y);

                for (int y=0; y<interpY; y++) {
                    outputTex.SetPixel(x,y,inputTex.GetPixel(x,y));
                }
                for (int y= interpY; y<size; y++) {
                    outputTex.SetPixel(x,y,bgcolor);
                }

            }

        }
        outputTex.Apply ();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What is the reason why the values should be between 0 and 1?

Comment: it was easier for me to program that way because that's what the uv coordinates require.  if your numbers are bigger, just divide them by the max number.  The lower left coord is `0,0` and upper right is `1,1`

Comment: Great! I will give it a try once I get time - will keep you posted. Thanks

Comment: I added a 2nd method of doing it as well.

Comment: Could you please award the bounty on this question?

Comment: I have applied your code into my working project but did not work..even with the normalized vector2 points. I will create a test project quickly to see if your code will work in a different scenario.

Comment: I have tested both - mesh working great, but the texture approach not as much. Please edit your answer to support Mesh only or supply a working Texture approach.

Comment: I tested the texture approach before submitting the answer. What is not working for you? It does require a mesh renderer attached and to fill the points array.

Comment: And the texture approach uses vector points that are not normalized.

Comment: I have tried the texture approach multiple times, rechecking the texture settings etc. Can you please post your sample project? I have also tried applying the the new generated texture to a sprite-renderer, just incase something weird is going on with the meshRend.